# How to make sure certain quotient spaces are homeomorphic to the sphere

Tags: general-topology

In proposition 6.1 of Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds, he claims that a closed 2-dimensional ball modulo (x,y) ~ (-x,y) for $(x,y) \in \partial B$ is homeomorphic to the 2-sphere. He says we can do this by creating a quotient map to $S^2$ and appealing to the uniqueness of quotient spaces, but wouldn't this just show that $\overline{B}^{2}$ is homeomorphic to the sphere under the quotient space topology we just created? Don't we need to show the sphere under this quotient topology is homeomorphic to the sphere under its subspace topology in $R^3$, or am I missing something here?

Thank you!

Comment: No, this would exactly prove the claim, i.e. that $\bar B^2/\sim$ (where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation involved) is homeomorphic to the sphere $S^2$ equipped with its usual topology (which has various descriptions, one of them being its subspace topology in $\Bbb R^3$).

Comment: How come? Do we know this proves the claim because we know the quotient topology must be homeomorphic to the usual topology somehow (ie it's one of those equivalent descriptions you mentioned)? Or is this true in more generality / for some other reason?

Comment: Let $X$ and $Y$ be spaces and $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $X$. Let $q:X\to Y$ be a quotient map. If we have $x\sim y\iff q(x)=q(y)$ then $X/_\sim\cong Y$ (canonically). As Anne says, this would prove exactly the claim

Comment: I suspect that what you are missing is the *topologic* (and not purely set-theoretic) notion of *quotient map*. $S^2$ comes equipped with its topology, and $q:\bar B^2\to S^2$ is not just a surjection such that $q(x)=q(y)\iff x\sim y.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Quotient_map

Comment: Yeah, I think I was missing the fact that the quotient map has to be continuous under the usual topology (it is in the example ussed in the book at least). Since it's continuous, the quotient topology is the  usual topology.